# How does tomcat access Servlets?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

As far my knowledge about JVM goes , it searches for main () method to start execution of a program. Now similarly Servlets are also java files (i believe) and they do not contain main method. How does Tomcat access them, does Tomcat has some main method like functionality inbuilt in it . Through which method does the container (i.e Tomcat) enters into a servlet? Do they do it via web.xml or something else.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet

Comment: Point 1.3 in servlet specification - http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat uses web.xml to know which servlets (classes) to instantiate.

Then Tomcat calls `init` method  method of the Servlet interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html).

When a servlet instance is ready, for every request the `service` is called. The `service` method is implemented in `HTTPServlet`(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) which then calls DoPost, DoGet, DoHead,... methods.

When the servlet instance is not needed any more the `destroy` method is invoked.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html as a general description and especially http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html for the full description of the lifecylce of servlets.